How I create a file to only my app can open it with VIEW intent?
So, my app is something like editor to specific data, which used in only my app(for now) and i want to have SEND and VIEW intent in app.
I tried to use a json files but with custom extensions, but in process i realized that i dont know which MIME type use then. application/{type} is used only with supported data types, so then i read documentation when said that i can use / instead, but google "strongly discourage doing so". Now i am numb and don`t know what should i do, may be anyone faced with challenge like that before?
